# Tennis terminology : how to use "coup droit / gauche"?

Tags: sport, terminologie

I've noticed that in French tennis commentary, they refer to a player's forehand as a 'coup droit' and their backhand as a 'coup gauche'.  However, isn't this assuming that the player is right-handed?  If they were left handed, these terms would be reversed.

If a player is left-handed, is a forehand still a 'coup droit' or does it become a 'coup gauche'?

Comment: It’s not *coup gauche*, it’s ***revers***!

Comment: Jamais entendu "coup gauche" non plus.

Comment: Maybe it's time to revise your accepted answer. This "coup gauche" thing looks like a urban legend, or close too.  *Droit* translates to 'straight' here, like in *aller tout droit*  means  'to go straight ahead', definitely not *aller à droite*.

Comment: @Jez ::::::: 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a player is left-handed, it is still a *coup droit*. I've never heard *coup gauche*, the usual technical word would be *revers*.

Source : [WP:FR](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Lexique_du_tennis#C)

Answer (score 10):

Les [termes employés au tennis](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Lexique_du_tennis) sont généralement « coup droit » et « revers ».

Un coup droit est un coup naturel quand la balle arrive à droite pour un droitier, ou à gauche pour un gaucher.
Un revers est un coup qui est souvent plus difficile à maîtriser.

Généralement [*un revers*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/revers) est un coup donné avec le dos de la main, ou avec une arme ou un instrument quelconque, de la gauche vers la droite dans le cas d’un droitier, de droite à gauche dans celui d’un gaucher.

(La raquette de tennis fait partie de ces instruments quelconques.)

Answer (score 5):

The expression "coup droit" is supposed to be used for right-handed players and "coup gauche" is the equivalent for left-handed players (see [coup droit](http://www.free-tennis.eu/-Coup-droit-.html)).

> Le saviez-vous ? Ce coup s’appelle normalement coup droit pour un
> droitier et coup gauche pour un gaucher. **Par abus de langage, on
> utilise le terme "coup droit" quelle soit la main principale du
> joueur**.

Usually, a player only uses one hand, and either "coup droit" or "revers".

Comment: Yeah, but plenty of left-handed players have one-handed forehands these days, and yet the term 'coup gauche' isn't used?